# C# Regex for changing occurrences of [ into [[] and ] into []]

Tags: c#, regex, select, datarow

I have a path + filename that contains [] several times. 
What i want to do is put [] around each [ as so:

*E:\Test\Bananas[in a cage]when[elephants]laugh.png*

Replaced into

*E:\Test\Bananas[[]in a cage[]]when[[]elephants[]]laugh.png*

The reason for this is here:

```
DataRow[] tempRows = filenames.Select("File like '" + tempLogElement + "'");
```

This will crash if a path containing square brackets appear. This is because [] are used to escape * and % in a this sort of 'like' statement. The way to avoid this is to escape the escape characters....

I am not awesome at Regex, but i've gotten aprox here:

```
Regex.Replace(tempLogElement, "(\[*\])", "[]]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This only escapes the ] character, but not the [ character.

This will not work:

```
tempLogElement.Replace("[","[[]").Replace("]","[]]")
```

The second replace would mess up the first replace. So i figured i had to use something that did it in one operation. And the first thing that came to mind was Regex.

Comment: Will the brackets in the input string always be in matched pairs? Or could an input string have `[` with no corresponding `]`?

Comment: Could be with no corresponding... this is a filename so it will be able to contain any combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Regex.Replace(tempLogElement, "\[([\w\s]*)\]", "[[]$1[]]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: hi,@rikitikitik,your regex not match the first string `[in a cage]`,should be change : `\[([\w\s]*)\]`

Comment: Shorter and sweeter. Just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short example:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\[|\]", "[$0]")
```

This matches either `[` or `]` and replaces with `[`...`]` containing the original character.

Answer (score 3):

Regex-less

```
tempLogElement.Replace("[", "[[").Replace("]", "[]]").Replace("[[", "[[]");
```

Comment: That's a smart one! i'll try to remember it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex _formatReplaceRegex = new Regex(@"\[([^\]]*)\]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string input = @"E:\Test\Bananas[in a cage]when[elephants]laugh.png";
Console.WriteLine(_formatReplaceRegex.Replace(input,"[[[$1]]]" );
```

--update Replace use $1 instead of anonymous method.--

Comment: Changed it so it worked for me:

                Regex fixString = new Regex(@"\[([^\]]*)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string test = fixString.Replace(tempLogElement, m => "[[]" + (m.Groups[1].Value) + "[]]");
                DataRow[] tempRows = filenames.Select("File like '" + test + "'");

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `String.Select`?

```
tempLogElement.Select(o => o == '[' ? "[[]" : (o == ']' ? "[[]" : o.ToString()));
```

or use a `for` iterartion

```
string temp = tempLogElement, replaced = "";
for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
{
    if (temp[i] == '[') replaced += "[[]";
    else if (temp[i] == ']') replaced += "[[]";
    else replaced += temp[i];
}
```

Comment: Umm... your second replace, would replace the items in the first!

Comment: This will cause the newly inserted right square bracket from the first replace to be replaced by the second.

Comment: The second replace would mess it all up. So i figured i had to use something that did it in one operation. And the first thing that came to mind was Regex.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Good thinking :)